# SQL Server 2012 Linked Server bug

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

When I run select from linked SQL Server 2012 like this:

```
select A.*
from A, (select TOP 1 * from B) as B
where A.test in (B.col1, B.col2)
```

I only get 1 row from A though A has many rows. B here is parameters table with only 1 row.

A and B here is synonyms which point to tables on remote server.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: What is your question here? It seems you have an answer already.

Comment: @marc_s, in this case your comment don't make sense to problem. I try it with inner join and got the same bug :)

Comment: @JamesZ - I just spent time with this bug and share it knowledge with others.

Comment: @marc_s is correct, bad habit to kick. Maintaining SQL code of this nature is just a nightmare. Especially when there are guys still coming through the ranks who need to build on a solid platform.

Comment: Please add your sample data and current result of your query ;).

Comment: Agree with @JamesZ - there is no question here. The correct place to report bugs is https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer. It might make a decent self answered question if phrased as a question and with sufficient details that we can reproduce the issue. (missing details such as local server version, remote server version, remote table definitions)

Answer (score 0):

We know that TOP without ORDER BY may produce non-deterministic results, but if we have only 1 row in table it must be OK. However, the MS SQL Server 2012 in case from question do his job very bad. To avoid such problem you have to write ORDER BY in nested table (B)! After that, query give right results. So, right query must be:

```
select A.*
from A, (select TOP 1 * from B ORDER BY <any field>) as B
where A.test in (B.col1, B.col2)
```

Take into account that SQL Server do well in case with local server but working differently in case of linked server.

Answer (score 0):

In your given query, the join structure is considered a
    CROSS JOIN 
, so by adding a filter in the
    WHERE 
clause you are effectively changing the join criteria to an
    INNER JOIN
following this join structure.  Also everyone else who will maintain your code will be better off if you use the ANSI-92 SQL Standard.

Consider a query like this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT col1 AS test FROM B
        UNION
        SELECT col2 AS test FROM B
    ) C 
    ON A.test = C.test
```

Comment: `FROM A,B` is a cross join not a full outer join.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith.. Correction applied